# Strange boolean value in Python Exception

Tags: python, exception

Recently I came across a strange part of code in one of the repositories I use for work. In this part, an exception is raised with a boolean value:

```
if current_run_row_count == 0:
        raise InconsistentData(
            "0 rows found", False,
        )
```

`InconsistentData` inherits from `Exception` class:

```
class InconsistentData(Exception):
    pass
```

I do not understand what this `False` corresponding to the exception raise does.

First my guess was that it is some marker whether this exception is actually a warning (I think I might have heard something like this). If it is `True`, then exception stops program execution, and if it is `False`, it does not stop it and acts as a warning. It could also be vice versa, but the idea is the same. However, I could not find any information about `Exception` arguments in Python documentation - for instance, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#Exception).

Secondly, I thought that maybe this `False` just does nothing and appears to be a part of the error message. I tested it with two different samples of code.

First one:

```
if 1 == 1:
    raise Exception("error", False)

print('Hello!')
```

Output:

```
Exception: ('error', False)
```

Second one:

```
if 1 == 1:
    raise Exception("error", True)

print('Hello!')
```

Output:

```
Exception: ('error', True)
```

So, in both code samples the exception is raised and stops program execution, and this boolean value seems to be a part of the error message. However, according to the code, I have no idea why would anyone include it in the error message. Along with `InconsistentData`, there are two other custom exceptions: `CustomException` and `ValidationError`, and when they are raised, they do not have any boolean values, only an error message represented with text.

Comment: It means whatever the author wants it to mean. It has no influence on the exception as such, as you have correctly identified. It's just additional data.

Comment: @deceze Thank you! I will accept your answer and close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably second option - "this False just does nothing and appears to be a part of the error message". I will accept [@deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) answer:

> It means whatever the author wants it to mean. It has no influence on the exception as such, as you have correctly identified. It's just additional data.